# Coupon collectors problem: solution through alternate route leads to expression hard to connect to result.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, coupon-collector

The identity I want help proving is the following (given $m$ probabilities, $p_j$ such that $\sum_j p_j = 1$):
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty t \sum\limits_j \left(\prod\limits_{k \neq j}(1-e^{-p_k t}) \right)e^{-p_jt}p_j dt =  \sum\limits_j\frac 1 p_j - \sum\limits_{i<j}\frac {1}{p_i+p_j} + \dots +(-1)^{m-1} \frac{1}{p_1+\dots+p_m}$$

For background and motivation, see below.

---

In example 5.17 of the book, [Introduction to probability models by Sheldon Ross](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/introduction-to-probability-model-s.ross-math-cs.blog_.ir_.pdf), the Coupon collector's problem is tackled for the general case where the probability of drawing coupon $j$ is given by $p_j$ and of course, $\sum\limits_j p_j = 1$. Now, he defines $X_j$ as the first time a coupon of type $j$ is observed, if the $j$th coupon arrives in accordance to a Poisson process with rate $p_j$. We're interested in the time it takes to collect all coupons, $X$. So we get:

$$X = \max_{1\leq j \leq m}X_j$$

Further, since the $X_j$ are independent (discussion on that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421101/poisson-mixture-process-independence-used-to-devastating-effect-on-the-coupon-co)), we get:

$$F_X(t) = P(X<t) = P(X_j<t \; \forall \; j) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^{m}(1-e^{-p_j t})\tag{1}$$

Now, Ross uses the expression: $E(X) = \int\limits_0^\infty S_X(t)dt$, where $S_X(t)$ is the survival function to get:

$$E(X) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\prod\limits_{j=1}^{m}(1-e^{-p_j t})\right) dt = \sum\limits_j\frac 1 p_j - \sum\limits_{i<j}\frac {1}{p_i+p_j} + \dots +(-1)^{m-1} \frac{1}{p_1+\dots+p_m}\tag{2}$$

Now, I want to get this same result using the old-fashioned definition of the expected value. For this, I differentiate equation (1) to get the PDF of $X$. First, let's take logarithm on both sides.

$$\log(F_X(t)) = \sum\limits_j \log(1-e^{-p_j t})$$

Now differentiate with respect to $t$.

$$\frac{f_X(t)}{F_X(t)} = \sum\limits_j \frac{p_j e^{-p_j t}}{1-e^{-p_j t}}$$

Finally yielding:

$$f_X(t) = \sum\limits_j \left(\prod\limits_{k \neq j}(1-e^{-p_k t}) \right)e^{-p_jt}p_j$$

Using this, we get an alternate expression for the expectation:

$$E(X) = \int\limits_0^\infty t f_X(t) dt = \int\limits_0^\infty t \sum\limits_j \left(\prod\limits_{k \neq j}(1-e^{-p_k t}) \right)e^{-p_jt}p_j dt$$

This should lead to the same expression as in equation (2). However, I don't know where to start. Why do I want to do it through this alternate route? Because I hope to find an expression for the variance as well and for that, need $E(X^2)$. Thought I'd tackle the easier, $E(X)$ for which we know there is a nice expression first.

Comment: Your question a day ago explained that rather than $1$ coupon per step, you have the arrivals of each of the coupon types as independent Poisson processes with rates $p_j$

Comment: Right, and this turns out to be equivalent to one coupon per step. Which is why I linked the earlier question and the book for background, but please let me know if I should add more of it in the question itself.

Comment: If you are only interested in $E[X^2]$, you may consider $E[X^2] = \int_0^{+\infty} x^2f(x)dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^{x} 2udu f(x)dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \int_u^{+\infty} f(x)dx 2u du = \int_0^{+\infty}2u[1-F(u)]du$

Comment: Thanks! That might actually work fine for what I was interested in. Let me see if I can solve it with this much simplified expression. This could have been an answer.

Comment: The correct expression for the expectation value should contain factors $(-1)^{||S||}$, where $||S||$ are cardinalities of corresponding subsets.

Comment: @user - good catch, fixed.

Comment: In the beginning of your question the signs remain unchanged. Besides you introduced new undefined variable $n $.

Comment: @BGM - I tried your approach to get $E(X^2)$ and the expression gets very close to the correct value, but misses one term. Haven't been able to figure out where it goes wrong in a long time. Asked another question about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439096/coupon-collectors-problem-variance-calculation-missing-a-term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity let $F = F_X$. For $L>0$ let 
$$I_L = \int_{0}^{L}tf_X(t)dt.$$ Using integration by parts, it follows that
\begin{align*}
I_L &= \int_{0}^{L}t F'(t) dt \\
&= tF(t)|_{0}^{L} - \int_{0}^{L} F(t) dt \\
&= L(F(L)-1) + J_L
\end{align*}
where 
$$J_L = \sum_{i=1}^{m} (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{0<j_1<...<j_i<m+1} \frac{1 - e^{-(p_{j_1}+...+p_{j_i})L}}{p_{j_1}+...+p_{j_i}}.$$
Show that 
$$\lim_{L\to\infty} L(F(L)-1) = 0.$$
Then it follows that
$$\lim_{L\to\infty} I_L = \lim_{L\to\infty} J_L = \sum_{i=1}^{m} (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{0<j_1<...<j_i<m+1} \frac{1}{p_{j_1}+...+p_{j_i}}.$$

For the $E(X^2)$ you might consider doing what I did here but applying integration by parts twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have an attempt at calculating the variance using the technique @BGM pointed out. The attempt is so far un-successful, but wanted to post it for my own reference and an answer seemed the best place given how long the question already is. As pointed out by @BGM,

$$E(X^2) = \int\limits_0^\infty 2u\left(1-F(u)\right) = \int\limits_0^\infty 2u\left(1-\prod\limits_{j=1}^m (1-e^{-p_j u})\right)du$$

$$ = \int\limits_0^\infty 2u\left(\sum e^{-{p_ju}} - \sum_{i<j} e^{-{(p_j+p_i)u}}+\dots+(-1)^{m+1}e^{-{(p_1+p_2+\dots+p_m)u}}\right)du$$

Now we know,

$$I = \int\limits_0^\infty u e^{-pu}du = \frac{1}{p^2}$$

$$=> E(X^2) = 2\left(\sum \frac{1}{p_j^2} + \sum_{i<j} \frac{1}{(p_i+p_j)^2} +\dots\right)$$

Trying to validate it for the case $p_j = \frac 1 m$ leads to some trouble. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435831/evaluating-the-expression-sum-limits-1n-1k-fracn-choose-kk2#3435831).