# Evaluating the expression: $\sum\limits_1^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n \choose k}{k^2}$

Tags: integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, coupon-collector

Per the title, I want to evaluate the expression:

$$S = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n \choose k}{k^2}$$

Looked on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%5Cleft(-1%5Cright)%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E2%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1) but no luck.

I think it has a nice closed form:

$$S = n^2\sum\frac{1}{i^2}+\left(n\sum \frac{1}{i}\right)^2$$

---

My attempt:

Using the Binomial theorem:

$$\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}{x^{k-1}}$$

Integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$.

$$\int\limits_0^x \frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}dx = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

For the LHS, let $1-x=u$

*EDIT: as pointed out by FDP, this is where the issue was. Limits of the integral need to be changed as well. See answer below for correct version.*

$$\int\limits_x^0 \frac{1-(u)^n}{1-u}(-du) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

$$=>\int\limits_0^x \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}u^{k} \right)du = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

$$=>\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k} {k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

$$=>\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{k-1}} {k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}$$

Integrating both sides from $0$ to $1$,

$$=>\int\limits_0^1\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{k-1}} {k} = \int\limits_0^1\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}$$

$$=>\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1} {k^2} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k^2}\tag{1}$$

Equation (1) is incorrect as evidenced by substituting $n=2$. Where did I go wrong?

---

Why do I care about this? It comes up in calculating the variance of the generalized coupon collector's problem. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424015/coupon-collectors-problem-solution-through-alternate-route-leads-to-expression).

Comment: It is $$\frac{1}{12} \left(-6 \psi ^{(0)}(n+1)^2-12 \gamma 
   \psi ^{(0)}(n+1)+6 \psi ^{(1)}(n+1)-\pi ^2-6 \gamma
   ^2\right)$$

Comment: Hmm, so no nice expression. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: When you perform the change of variable $u=1-t$, $\displaystyle \int_0^x\dfrac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}\,dt$ the result is $\displaystyle \int_{1-x}^1\dfrac{1-u^n}{1-u}\,du$

Comment: A special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232079) of mine.

Comment: @FDP Good catch.

Comment: @Damien - that was a bit of abuse of notation. Just replace the $x$ inside the integral with $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comment by @FDP, I managed to correct the Math. Starting over:

Using the Binomial theorem:

$$\frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}{t^{k-1}}$$

Integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$.

$$\int\limits_0^x \frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}dx = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

For the LHS, let $1-t=u$

$$\int\limits_1^{1-x} \frac{1-(u)^n}{1-u}(-du) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1-(1-x)^k}{k}}{x} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{n\choose k}{k}x^{k-1}$$

Integrate both sides from $0$ to $1$, we get:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \int\limits_0^1 \frac{1-(1-x)^k}{x} dx = \sum \frac{n \choose k}{k^2} (-1)^{k-1}$$

Substituting $1-x=t$ in the integral and expanding the geometric series we get:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac 1 j = \sum \frac{n \choose k}{k^2} (-1)^{k-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac {1}{jk}$$

---

This can very easily be extended to $k^r$ in the denominator:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n\choose k}{k^r}=\sum_{i_1<i_2<\dots <i_r}\frac{1}{i_1 i_2 \dots i_r}$$

and the following code verifies this upto three terms in the denominator:

```
def binom_trms(n,r):
    summ = 0
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        summ += (-1)**(k-1)*comb(n,k)/k**r
    return summ


def inverses_3(n):
    summ = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            for k in range(1,j+1):
                summ+=1/i/j/k
    return summ


def inverses_2(n):
    summ = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            summ+=1/i/j
    return summ
```

Comment: I suppose that you need to multiply the last term by $-1$.

Comment: Right, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @user90369 - thanks, fixed all the things you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

The general expression given in comments can write
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac{n \choose k}{k^2}=\frac{\psi ^{(1)}(n+1)}{2}-\frac{\left(H_n\right){}^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$

For large enough values of $n$, you could use asymptotics and get
$$S_n=\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \log ^2\left({n}\right)-12 \gamma  \log
   \left({n}\right)-\pi ^2-6 \gamma ^2\right)-\frac{\log
   \left({n}\right)+\gamma -1}{2 n}+\frac{2 \log
   \left({n}\right)+2 \gamma -9}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which is in relative error lower  than $0.1$% if $n \geq 4$ and lower  than $0.01$% if $n \geq 7$ .

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k - 1}{{n \choose k} \over k^{2}}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k - 1}{n \choose k}
\bracks{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}x^{k - 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-x}^{k}
\,{\dd x \over x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{n} - 1} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{x^{\mu - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{n} - x^{\mu - 1}} \,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{\large +}} \\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + n + 1}} - {1 \over \mu}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{\large +}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{{1 \over \mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + n + 1}} - 1}}
_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{\large +}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + n + 1}} - 1}
_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{\large +}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}
{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
\over \Gamma\pars{\mu + n + 1}}\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{\large +}} \\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\large {\pi^{2} \over 12} + {1 \over 2}\,H_{n}^{2} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Psi\, '\pars{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] &\
\end{align}